# inline HTML javascript event intreprets escaped quote as a closing quote

Tags: javascript, php, html, escaping, xss

Is it so that inline HTML js events doesn't care about escaped quotes?

```
$xss = addslashes("'><script>alert(/XSS/.source)</script>");
echo "<a href='/deleteaction.php' onclick='javascript:if(!confirm(\"{$xss}\")) return false'>Delete</a>";
```

Produced HTML:

```
<a href='/deleteaction.php' onclick='javascript:if(!confirm("\'>
<script>alert(/XSS/.source)</script>
")) return false'>Delete</a>
```

EDIT: So this actually executes the script. I thought it would produce string like this in to the confirm box:

```
'><script>alert(/XSS/.source)</script>
```

But first single quote is interpret as closing quote for onclick event. So my question is that why it is interpret as closing quote eventhough it has backslash before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser's HTML parser runs before the JavaScript parser.

In HTML `\'` is not recognised as a single quote character, it is recognised as literally a backslash followed by a single quote.

The correct HTML for a single quote is `&#x27;` (or `&#039;` in decimal).

To fix it you should use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) as well as `addslashes`.

e.g.

```
$xss = addslashes(htmlentities("'><script>alert(/XSS/.source)</script>", ENT_QUOTES));
```

This will output:

```
<a href='/deleteaction.php' onclick='javascript:if(!confirm("&#039;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(/XSS/.source)&lt;/script&gt;")) return false'>Delete</a>
```

Which is the correct encoding for the confirm to be shown as:

[image: PHP XSS]

Note that this only applies to HTML attributes that can contain script, not content within `<script>` tags, because that content is not ran through the HTML parser (the HTML parser just looks for the final `</script>` until it resume HTML processing).

Note we need `addslashes` too in case the string contains `\` characters.

A less messy way of coding this is to follow [Rule #3 of the OWASP XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values):

> Except for alphanumeric characters, escape all characters less than
>   256 with the \xHH format to prevent switching out of the data value
>   into the script context or into another attribute.

So rather than encoding for both slashes and HTML, we simply JavaScript hex entity encode. To my knowledge PHP does not offer this out of the box (although please correct me if I'm wrong).

This also handles the situation where there attributes are single quoted, double quoted or unquoted (as space is converted to `\x20`).

Answer (score 0):

This is correct $xss value. You missed a single quotation at the end.

```
$xss = addslashes("'><script>alert(/XSS/.source)</script>'");
```

**Edited**

We cannot directly use < and > tags in our code as those are standard html tags reserved for html tags, instead use the html entities

```
$xss = addslashes("'&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(/XSS/.source)&lt;/script&gt;'");
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but that really wasn't my problem, I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: @Aleksi in your code of $xss replace > with &gt;  and < with &lt; i edited my reply please look at it. We cannot directly use < and > tags in our code as those are standard html tags reserved for html tags, instead use the html entities

Comment: Yes I undestand that html tags should be escaped but in this problem it is not relevant. < and > characters are just used to demonstrate potential XSS vulnerability which is caused by \' before the script. I don't understand why \' isn't treated like &#39; the escaped version of '.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/script_tags.html

> The values of event handling attributes will almost certainly need to
>   be quoted because it is nearly impossible to write a javascript
>   statement that only uses the characters allowed in an unquoted
>   attribute value. And quoting can get quite involved in attribute
>   values because they need to be quoted in the HTML source so whatever
>   type of quote marks are used in the HTML cannot be used within the
>   javascript code provided as the value because the HTML parser would
>   take them as ending the string for the attribute value. While
>   javascript string literals allow the use of double quotes or single
>   quotes as delimiters and allow the type of quote not used as the
>   delimiter to appear within the string literal unescaped.
>
> So, given a desire to assign the string "don't do that" to an
>   element's value property in an onclick event, because of the single
>   quote appearing in the string itself the attribute value
>   onclick='this.value = "don't do that";' will not work because the HTML
>   parser will take the second single quote as ending the attribute
>   value. It will not work to simply escape the single quote as
>   onclick='this.value = "don\'t do that";' because the HTML parser
>   doesn't know anything about javascript escapes and still sees the
>   second single quote in the middle of the javascript string.
>
> In this case escaping the single quote and reversing the quoting
>   between the HTML and the javascript onclick="this.value = 'don\'t do
>   that';" or using a javascript hex escape (which the HTML parser will
>   not see as a quote) onclick='this.value = "don\x27t do that";' would
>   solve the problem. But quotes in event handling attribute strings that
>   define code that uses string literals often needs to be thought about.